# PHP Get Value from JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have an Index.php file, which contain a simple js,php language for getting a value from javascript, but I can't do that. can you tell me about how to do it?
**Here is My index.php Wrong Syntax File:**

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
   var foo = "bar";
</script>
<?php
   $fromJS = "<script>var jsfoo = foo;</script>";
   echo $fromJS;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot do that. PHP runs before JS.

Comment: Php is evaluated server side and js client side. This will never work

Comment: PHP is run on the server before JS even begins to execute.  I don't know what you're trying to do, but you can't do it

Comment: You could do this by sending an AJAX request. Anyway, as you posted it, I don't see why you would want this.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right you want to set a variable in JavaScript and read its value in PHP.
If that's right, it is not possible that way. The reason is really simple:
PHP will be executed inside the HTTP server on the server side, while JavaScript is executed in the browser on the client side.

To pass the value of a JavaScript variable to PHP you have to initiate a request to your PHP script and add the value to the PSOT or GET request.

A very simple example:

The JavaScript part

```
var foo = 'bar';
window.location.href = '/path/to/script.php?foo=' + foo;
```

And the PHP part

```
<?php
echo htmlentities($_REQUEST['foo']);
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, *at least not the way you have here*.

PHP is a **server-side** language, and thus is executed as the page is rendered to the response, which is then passed back to the client (the browser).

JavaScript is a **client-side** language, and isn't executed until it is read by the browser. Therefore, it is not possible to pass the client-side data (the JavaScript) to the server (PHP) *as you have it here*.

The only way you can achieve this is to have another page which POSTs or GETs data to a PHP via JavaScript (using a form submit or an XMLHTTPRequest, etc), and then process the posted data from within PHP that way.

Here's a really simple example which performs a GET against the PHP page:

On the client side (JavaScript):

```
window.location.href = "http://yoursite.com/page.php?foo=bar";
```

On the server side (PHP):

```
<?php 
echo htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['foo']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden iframe and a submit a form within the iframe with the variable you want to send to your script. Also all DOM manipulations can be done from the iframe.

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="ifrm" src="iframe.php" width="1" height="1" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<script>
    var foo = "bar";
// I assume you are using jQuery
    jQuery('ifrm').contents().find('#inpt').val(foo);
    jQuery('ifrm').contents().find('form').submit();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

iframe.php

```
<html>
<!-- include jQuery or whatever -->
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['inpt'])) {
// Do your manipulations here

    echo '<script type="text/javscript">';
// retrieve iframes parent (your webpage)
    echo 'let parent = window.parent.document.body';
// do anything you want
    echo 'parent.style.backgroundColor = \'#ff0000\'';
    echo '</script>';
}
?>
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="inpt" name="inpt" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Should work like this, but keep in mind - I haven't tested the above code.
But you should get the idea.

Have fun with it.